# How can I suppress unchecked cast warnings?

Tags: kotlin

Having the following code:

```
fun doSomething(): List<String> {

    val test: List<*> = arrayListOf("test1", "test2")

    return test as List<String>
}
```

Is there some way to suppress the unchecked cast warning that comes up in the last line? I tried to use the standard Java way `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` at the method level, but it didn't work.

Comment: `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` works well for IDEA 15.0.4. Just press Alt+Enter on highlighted `test as List<String>` and use *"Suppress 'UNCHECKED_CAST' for fun doSomething"*

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Adding `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` (also possible through IDEA's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> menu) to any of *statement*, *function*, *class* and *file* should help.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: @Suppress? What package is that in?

Comment: @flodin, https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-suppress/

Comment: Is there a document available anywhere stating all the "suppressables" for kotlin or java?