# Kotlin: How to work with List casts: Unchecked Cast: kotlin.collections.List<Kotlin.Any?> to kotlin.colletions.List<Waypoint>

Tags: list, generics, casting, kotlin

I want to write a function that returns every item in a `List` that is not the first or the last item (a via point). The function gets a generic `List<*>` as input. A result should only be returned if the elements of the list are of the type `Waypoint`:

```
fun getViaPoints(list: List<*>): List<Waypoint>? {

    list.forEach { if(it !is Waypoint ) return null }

    val waypointList = list as? List<Waypoint> ?: return null

    return waypointList.filter{ waypointList.indexOf(it) != 0 && waypointList.indexOf(it) != waypointList.lastIndex}
}
```

When casting the `List<*>` to `List<Waypoint>`, I get the warning:

> Unchecked Cast: kotlin.collections.List
>   to kotlin.colletions.List

I can't figure out a way to implement it otherwise. What's the right way to implement this function without this warning?

Answer (score 342, accepted):

In Kotlin, there's no way to check the generic parameters at runtime in general case (like just checking the items of a `List<T>`, which is only a special case), so casting a generic type to another with different generic parameters will raise a warning unless the cast lies within [variance bounds](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance).

There are different solutions, however:

- You have checked the type and you are quite sure that the cast is safe. Given that, you can [suppress the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221405/how-can-i-suppress-unchecked-cast-warnings/36221525#36221525) with `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`.

  ```
  @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
  val waypointList = list as? List<Waypoint> ?: return null
  ```
- Use [`.filterIsInstance<T>()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html) function, which checks the item types and returns a list with the items of the passed type:

  ```
  val waypointList: List<Waypoint> = list.filterIsInstance<Waypoint>()

  if (waypointList.size != list.size)
      return null
  ```

  or the same in one statement:

  ```
  val waypointList = list.filterIsInstance<Waypoint>()
      .apply { if (size != list.size) return null }
  ```

  This will create a new list of the desired type (thus avoiding unchecked cast inside), introducing a little overhead, but in the same time it saves you from iterating through the `list` and checking the types (in `list.foreach { ... }` line), so it won't be noticeable.
- Write a utility function that checks the type and returns the same list if the type is correct, thus encapsulating the cast (still unchecked from the compiler's point of view) inside it:

  ```
  @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
  inline fun <reified T : Any> List<*>.checkItemsAre() =
          if (all { it is T })
              this as List<T>
          else null
  ```

  With the usage:

  ```
  val waypointList = list.checkItemsAre<Waypoint>() ?: return null
  ```

Comment: Great Answer! I choose list.filterIsInstance<Waypoint>() solution because I think it's the cleanest solution.

Comment: Note that if you use [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html) and the original list contains elements of a different type your code will silently filter them out. Sometimes this is what you want but sometimes you might rather have an `IllegalStateException` or similar thrown. If the later is the case then you can create your own method to check and then cast: `inline fun <reified R> Iterable<*>.mapAsInstance() = map { it.apply { check(this is R) } as R }`

Comment: Note that `.apply` does not return the return value of the lambda, it returns the receive object.  You probably want to use `.takeIf` if you want the option to return a null.

Comment: What's the performance overhead of `filterIsInstance` over `Unchecked cast` on JVM (Android)?

Answer (score 23):

To improve @hotkey's answer here's my solution:

```
val waypointList = list.filterIsInstance<Waypoint>().takeIf { it.size == list.size }
```

This gives you the `List<Waypoint>` if all the items can be casted, null otherwise.

Answer (score 10):

In case of generic classes casts cannot be checked because type information is erased in runtime. But you check that all objects in the list are `Waypoint`s so you can just suppress the warning with `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`.

To avoid such warnings you have to pass a `List` of objects convertible to `Waypoint`. When you're using `*` but trying to access this list as a typed list you'll always need a cast and this cast will be unchecked.

Answer (score 6):

I made a little variation to @hotkey answer when used to check Serializable to List  objects :

```
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    inline fun <reified T : Any> Serializable.checkSerializableIsListOf() =
        if (this is List<*> && this.all { it is T })
          this as List<T>
        else null
```

Comment: Was looking for a solution like this, but this errors: `Cannot access 'Serializable': it is internal in 'kotlin.io'`

Comment: solution: In android to pass a user-defined object around, your class should implements Parcelable instead of Serializable interface.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
myGenericList.filter { it is AbstractRobotTurn } as List<AbstractRobotTurn>
```

I like doing

```
myGenericList.filter { it is AbstractRobotTurn }.map { it as AbstractRobotTurn }
```

Not sure how performant this is, but no warnings at least.

Comment: `myGenericList.filterIsInstance<AbstractRobotTurn>` seems to be better

Answer (score 0):

> Kotlin ensures type safety for operations involving generics at compile time, while, at runtime, instances of generic types don't hold information about their actual type arguments. For example, List is erased to just List<*>. **In general, there is no way to check whether an instance belongs to a generic type with certain type arguments at runtime.**

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#type-erasure-and-generic-type-checks