# Kotlin how to try/catch a cast

Tags: android, kotlin

I am storing shared preferences value as a `HashSet` and when retrieving I see the warning about unchecked casting. What is the most simple and what is the safest solution to ensure bug free implementation here?

```kotlin
class TaskListDataManager(private val context: Context) {
    fun saveList(taskList: TaskList) {
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()

        sharedPreferences.putStringSet(taskList.name, taskList.taskList.toHashSet())

        sharedPreferences.apply()
    }

    fun readList(): ArrayList<TaskList> {
        val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
        val taskLists = sharedPreferences.all.map {
            TaskList(it.key, ArrayList(it.value as HashSet<String>))
        }

        return ArrayList<TaskList>(taskLists)
    }
}
```

[image: kotlin code example]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36569421/kotlin-how-to-work-with-list-casts-unchecked-cast-kotlin-collections-listkot

Comment: Use `as?` instead and provide a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
try{    
   //code that may throw exception    
}catch(e: SomeException){  
   //code that handles exception  
}finally {  
   // optional finally block  
}
```

Comment: How do you know the exception type that a bad cast will throw?

Comment: @CoryRobinson `e: Exception`. It will cast any type of `exception`.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the `try/catch` block, you can also safely unwrap it while putting in the model.

```
(a.value as? HashSet<String>)?.let {
   TaskList(a.key, ArrayList(it))
}
```

Comment: Thx @Himanshu. This is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
kotlin.runCatching { }.onFailure {  }
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.