# Kotlin syntax for inferring generic supertype from subtype

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-interop

Trying to call existing Java code that expects a `Class` as a parameter, I tried code along the lines of this in Kotlin:

```
package com.example

//Acutally imported Java code in someone elses's library
abstract class JavaCode<T> {
    fun doTheThing(thing: Class<JavaCode<T>>) {
        //Does work
    }
}

//My code
class KotlinCode : JavaCode<String>() {
    fun startTheThing() {
        doTheThing(KotlinCode::class.java)
    }                             // ^ Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch
}
```

But that does not compile with the following error:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Class<KotlinCode> but Class<JavaCode<String>> was expected
```

So I tried to force a cast (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982630/inferring-a-generic-type-of-map-in-kotlin)):

```
hello(GenericArgument::class.java as Class<Callable<String>>)
```

But that has a warning:

```
Unchecked cast: Class<KotlinCode> to Class<JavaCode<String>>
```

So what is the correct syntax to use? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43983008/4822566) related?

Comment: Because `Callable<String?>` != `Callable<String>`, have you tried to declare `class GenericArgument : Callable<String>` ?

Comment: That just changes the expected type mismatch to `Class<Callable<String>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

First, `Callable<String?>` is no equal to `Callable<String>`. `Callable<String?>` means the argument can be `String` or `null` but `Callable<String>` is `String` only.

Second, `Class<GenericArgument>` does not implement `Class<Callable<String>>` but `GenericArgument` implements `Callable<String>`. they are different. You can change it to use generic instead.

```
private fun <T : Callable<String>> hello(callable: Class<T>) {
    System.out.println(callable.toString())
}
```

Now, the generic parameter is bound by `Callable<String>`.

Third, `callable.toString()` probably does not do what you want. `callable.toString()`  will call the `toString()` of the class instead of object, e.g. `class com.example.yourclass`. If you want to call the object `toString()`. This is the correct one.

```
override fun call(): String {
    hello(GenericArgument())
    return "value"
}

private fun <T : Callable<String>> hello(callable: T) {
    System.out.println(callable.toString())
}
```

Moreover, Kotlin allows to pass function as parameter or use SAM for interface. Implementing for `Callable` is not necessary.

Edit: As op updated the question.

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <T, U : JavaCode<T>> JavaCode<T>.doTheThing2(thing: Class<U>) {
    doTheThing(thing as Class<JavaCode<T>>)
}
```

Comment: I understand there is a difference between `String` and `String?`. After that, perhaps my example breaks down a little. It's actually an abstract Java class that I'm extending. The method I want to use is on the base class. That is someone else's library, making changes difficult. It's not actually a `Callable`; that was just to provide an example with the same problem. I also realise that `callable.toString()` isn't particularly useful. Once again, that was just to prove the point. It sounds like I have to change the callee (`hello`), but the caller (`call`) is the bit I can modify.

Comment: @AlexTaylor Java does not have generic metadata at runtime so generic cast can result in error.

Comment: And Kotlin provides no ability to guard against it? Basically, the Java code couldn't provide runtime type safety in this situation, but Kotlin gives you a warning? I've updated the code with something closer to my real code.

Comment: @AlexTaylor This is the JVM limitation not Java code. Kotlin compile its code to run on JVM. Kotlin give you a warning because it cannot be checked. I will have to look at your code later as I am going out for lunch.

Comment: @AlexTaylor  See my edit. After your update, your example only solution is force cast. But you can improve safety by implement a Kotlin function to do the force cast instead of everywhere that you call the method.

Comment: OK, so we separate out the cast as a function so the suppression only affects the problem code. Got it.