# How to safely cast a reflected class in Kotlin

Tags: reflection, kotlin, casting, type-erasure

I need to dynamically load classes at runtime in Kotlin. I would like to check that they implement my interface, and if so, all green. Unfortunately, Kotlin's "smart casts" is failing me:

```
var className = "some.class.Name"
val unsafeClass = Class.forName(className).kotlin
require(unsafeClass.isSubclassOf(MyInterface::class)) {
    "Class '$className' is not a MyInterface"
}
val safeClass = unsafeClass as KClass<MyInterface>
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                            Unchecked cast: KClass<out Any!> to KClass<MyInterface>
```

I'm clearly checking that the class implements the given interface. Can I re-phrase this code to avoid the warning?

I tried to test with `is KClass<MyInterface>` but I get a type erasure error (obviously, because the generic type information disappears at runtime.)

---

Edit: to clarify, my application needs to read class names `"some.class.Name"` at startup, during configuration; load those classes; check that they satisfy an interface; and store a Class or KClass reference for later. During runtime, it will use those references to create objects, using `cls.createInstance()` or such.

My question: is there any way to do so without getting unsafe cast warnings?

I can either get a warning at configuration time, when I cast the `KClass<*>` to `KClass<MyInterface>` (even though I `require`d the class to be a subclass) but then I get no warning later on, because `.createInstance()` on a `KClass<MyInterface>` class reference returns a type-checked `MyInterface` instance.

Or, I can store the references as `KClass<*>`, without warnings at configuration time, but then I'll get the warning in the place where I create the instances, because I'll need to unsafe cast `Object` instances to `MyInterface`.

Is there any solution that will satisfy the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cast is not only unchecked, it's actually incorrect: because `AMyInterfaceImpl::class` has type `KClass<AMyInterfaceImpl>` and `KClass` is not covariant (for good reason), it does *not* have the type `KClass<MyInterface>`. You can see that from this code not compiling:

```
class AMyInterfaceImpl : MyInterface { ... }

val cls: KClass<MyInterface> = AMyInterfaceImpl::class
```

So if the cast could be checked, it would fail.

`KClass<out MyInterface>` would be correct, but I don't think the compiler will understand this and allow smart cast. It's just too rarely useful to teach the compiler.

Comment: Thank you. I have expanded my question. So what `Class<...>` or `KClass<...>` reference should I store, if I want to be able to create instances of objects that satisfy `MyInterface`? Should I use `KClass<*>`, and do an unsafe cast at every object creation time? Or do an unsafe cast to obtain the `KClass<out MyInterface>`, which then means I don't need casts to create the instances? Can I get rid of both warnings, or is it impossible?

Comment: Why are you getting warnings if using `KClass<*>`? Cast to `MyInterface` is checked, and you could even test `is MyInterface` to avoid explicit cast, but I don't think there's much win there.

Comment: You can use `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221405/how-can-i-suppress-unchecked-cast-warnings to suppress the warnings. At runtime both ways are actually _exactly_ the same: cast to `KClass<out MyInterface>` doesn't exist, and the compiler inserts casts to `MyInterface` where needed. So use whichever is more readable.

Answer (score 4):

JVM and Kotlin implement generics only at the compiler level. One cannot see generic parameters of a generic class at runtime. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

At runtime, there is no difference between `Class<*>` and `Class<MyInterface>`. These two are the same instance of `Class` type.

The warning that you have means that you have no information in the generic parameter at runtime, a compiler cannot validate it too, and it only can trust you

I do not see the reason cast the `KClass` to the `KClass<MyInterface>`. It is only necessary for an object, not it's class. Also, it probably can be simplified to use `Class<*>` instead, e.g:

```
val className = "some.class.Name"
val unsafeClass = Class.forName(className)
require(MyInterface::class.java.isAssignableFrom(unsafeClass)) {
    "Class '$className' is not a MyInterface"
}
val safe = unsafeClass.newInstance() as MyInterface
```

Comment: Thank you. I have expanded my question. The reason to cast the `KClass<*>` to `KClass<MyInterface>` is to avoid having to cast all the objects that I will create later on.

Comment: For the cast it is equal to use KClass<YourClass> or Class<YourClass>. You have a `Class<?>` from the `Class.forName` call. You need an explicit cast or an unsafe cast anyways