# How to call Java method expecting a parameter which is a class with generics in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, ignite

I am looking to call the following Java method signature from Kotlin

```
    <C extends javax.cache.configuration.Configuration<K,V>> C getConfiguration(Class<C> clazz)
```

from https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.7.5/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#getConfiguration-java.lang.Class-

I think in Java the standard way would be to call

```
    CacheConfiguration configuration = igniteCache.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration.class);
```

I can't figure out how to express this in Kotlin to get this object.

I've tried

```
   val configuration = igniteCache.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration::class.java)
```

but this gives me the following error

```
    Type mismatch: inferred type is CacheConfiguration<*, *> but Configuration<K!, V!>! was expected
```

So what is the correct way to call this method?

---

Update

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57016668/10039185 provided the answer how to do this.

I'm just adding two snippets with fuller Ignite specific examples of how to do this

Using unchecked cast

```
private fun <K, V> checkCacheUsingUncheckedCast(igniteCache: IgniteCache<K, V>?) {
    val configuration = igniteCache?.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration::class.java as Class<CacheConfiguration<K, V>>)
    if (configuration != null) {
        // do something with the configuration
    }
}
```

Using reified type

```
private fun <K, V> checkCacheUsingReifiedType(igniteCache: IgniteCache<K, V>?) {
    val configuration = igniteCache?.configuration<K, V, CacheConfiguration<K, V>>()
    if (configuration != null) {
        // do something with the configuration
    }
}

private inline fun <K, V, reified C : Configuration<K, V>> IgniteCache<K, V>.configuration() = getConfiguration(C::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think in Java the standard way would be to call
>
> ```
> CacheConfiguration configuration = igniteCache.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration.class);
> ```

Because `CacheConfiguration` [requires two type parameters](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.7.5/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#getRebalanceDelay--), this is a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it) and not a good idea to use it. It should be

```
CacheConfiguration<KeyType, ValueType> configuration = (CacheConfiguration<KeyType, ValueType>) igniteCache.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration.class);
```

or

```
var configuration = (CacheConfiguration<KeyType, ValueType>) igniteCache.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration.class);
```

where `KeyType` and `ValueType` correspond to the type parameters of `igniteCache`. Note that the cast is necessary.

Similarly in Kotlin,

```
val configuration = igniteCache.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration::class.java as Class<CacheConfiguration<KeyType, ValueType>>)
```

But you can define a helper function with [reified generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters):

```
inline fun <K, V, reified C : Configuration<K, V>> IgniteCache<K, V>.configuration() = getConfiguration(C::class.java)
```

and then call it as

```
val configuration = igniteCache.configuration<CacheConfiguration<KeyType, ValueType>>()
```

Comment: Trying your suggestion above:

`val configuration = igniteCache.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration::class.java) as CacheConfiguration<String, String>`


still results in 

`Type mismatch: inferred type is CacheConfiguration<*, *> but Configuration<K!, V!>! was expected`

for the CacheConfiguration::class.java part of the line

Comment: Ok, then the cast needs to be elsewhere, try the edited version.

Comment: The non-reified version works but has the expected warning `Unchecked cast: Class<CacheConfiguration<*, *>> to Class<CacheConfiguration<K, V>>`.  

The reified version removes the warning but needs to be called as `val configuration = igniteCache?.configuration<K, V, CacheConfiguration<K, V>>()`

Comment: You can use `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` to fix the first problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221405/how-can-i-suppress-unchecked-cast-warnings)