# Kotlin checked cast from Any? to Map<String,Any>

Tags: kotlin, casting

I have `Any?` coming from java and I would like to make a checked cast in order not to generate following warning:

[image: Unchecked cast Any? to Map<String,Any>]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can cast to `Map<*, *>`, but there's no way to check the type parameters. If you are sure that *if* it's a `Map`, then it's a `Map<String, Any>` (that is, all keys are `String`s and values are never `null`) then just cast and [suppress the warning with `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221405/how-can-i-suppress-unchecked-cast-warnings).