# Kotlin: Cannot convert Map to JSON

Tags: java, json, kotlin, hashmap

How to convert `Map` to `JSONObject`? It accepts `Map` but it seems you need to perform casting. Is there any other way to do this without using library?

[image]

Comment: Please share your code as code instead as image.

Comment: I doubt answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58537743/kotlin-checked-cast-from-any-to-mapstring-any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer provided by Bitwise DEVS may work, but the explanation is incorrect.

It is not necessary to convert the map into an immutable map - it can even be seen in the screenshot of the question: `expected (Mutable)Map` means that it can be mutable or immutable.

The real problem here is that the called constructor of `JSONObject` is defined for `Map<Any?, Any?>` but the given parameter is of type `Map<String!, String!>`. We know that `String` is a subtype of `Any?`, so why is that a problem?

It is a problem because `Map` is *invariant* in the key parameter which means that a `Map<A, V>` is not subtype of `Map<B, V>` even if `A` is subtype of `B` (and also not if it is the other way around).

The call of `toMap` does not work because it makes the map immutable, but because it is defined as

```
fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.toMap(): Map<K, V>
```

In the receiver type of `toMap` the key parameter is annotated with the `out` modifier, meaning that `K` is *covariant* here. This means that a `Map<Any, V>` in this position can safely be considered as a supertype of `Map<String, V>`. Additionally, `Map` is always *covariant* in its value type, meaning that `Map<Any, Any>` in this position can safely be considered as a supertype of `Map<String, String>`.

You could as well just cast `remoteMessage.data as Map<Any?, Any?>` or use `toMutableMap`, it would be all the same. It has *definitely nothing* to do with mutability of the map.

Kotlin documentation on variance: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#declaration-site-variance

Kotlin documentation of `Map`: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/

Definition of `toMap`: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ea836fd46a1fef07d77c96f9d7e8d7807f793453/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Maps.kt#L600

Comment: Wow, rarely received such a great and detailed answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just realized the answer, if you are using Map like `Map<String, String>` in Kotlin there is a mutable and immutable version of it. In the question above all you need to do is to convert it to immutable Map using `toMap()`.

```
val msgData = parser.fromJsonString<CommonNotification>(
            JSONObject(remoteMessage.data.toMap()).toString(),
            CommonNotification::class.java
        ) ?: return
```