# In Kotlin, how can I get a class from a string and assign it to a variable with superclass type?

Tags: kotlin

Right now I am using this line:
`klass = Class.forName({MyClassName}).kotlin as KClass<{MySuperClassName}>`

But I am getting an 'unchecked cast' warning

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cast is actually incorrect; a `Class<{MyClassName}>` is *not* a `Class<{MySuperClassName}>`. It only doesn't throw an exception because, as the warning says, the cast is unchecked. The type you probably want is `Class<out {MySuperClassName}>` (meaning basically `Class<some subtype of {MySuperClassName}>`).

Fixing the type won't fix the warning for reason already explained in Sir Codesalot's answer.

But you can [suppress the warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221405/how-can-i-suppress-unchecked-cast-warnings) with `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` because no, there is no better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to avoid this warning because `.kotlin` is an extension of `<T : Any> Class<T>` and that's what `Class.forName()` is returning (when translated from Java). So what you're actually doing looks like this:

```
Class.forName() -> Class<T: Any>.kotlin -> KClass<T: Any> as KClass<{MySuperClassName}>
```

You are casting `KClass<T: Any>` to `KClass<{MySuperClassName}>` and that will always produce a warning because the compiler can't tell if `MySuperClassName` is in fact a descendant of `T` because `T` can be anything at this point.